# How to trigger jenkins build upon bitbucket pull request merged

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I looked at all other related questions and answers, didn't find anything solid, hence I'm opening a new question to look for your kind help, I've been working on this the whole day, any help I can get would be highly appreciated.

Here's my environment:

- self-hosted jenkins server (Jenkins ver. 1.651.3) with git and bitbucket plugin installed.
- https://bitbucket.org (I do not have a self-hosted bitbucket server)

What I want to do: **to trigger jenkins build upon pull request got merged from feature branch to master branch.**

Different setting combinations which I had tried:

1. - jenkins: 'Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket' checked.
   - bitbucket: web hooks trigger: 'Repository push' checked.

Result: build was triggered successfully upon commit to master branch, but that's not what I want, but at least I know the communication between my jenkins server and bitbucket is fine.

2. - jenkins: 'Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket' checked.
   - bitbucket: web hooks trigger: 'Repository push' checked, and Pull Request - 'Merged' checked.

Result: jenkins does not respond to the pull request merged action. I assumed it would work since I had the Pull Requst - 'Merged' checked in the web hooks trigger setting, and I did see the request was sent by bitbucket to my jenkins server, and it got 200 status code back from my jenkins server, but still, nothing happens.

3. - jenkins: 'Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket' checked. And besides that, I installed another plugin called bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin, and configured it according to the instruction.
   - bitbucket: web hooks trigger: 'Repository push' checked, and Pull Request - 'Merged' checked.

Result: with the help of bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin, the build was indeed triggered upon pull request created. But the jenkins server polls the bitbucket repository constantly, and I didn't find a way to stop that, no way to trigger build ONLY upon merge neither...

I heard there's people says that you'll need to install a post-hook plugin on the bitbucket server in order to do what I want to do, but the thing is I dont host the bitbucket...

Comment: I feel this question belongs to https://answers.atlassian.com. I am having similar issues and found a few helpful posts there.

Comment: @Tylr Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: If you are the admin to the bitbucket server, you can install plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some research you can have a few options as of today Nov 12 of 2017:

- Use the generic [post webhooks plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/nl.topicus.bitbucket.bitbucket-webhooks/server/overview) that supports pull request trigger. And from jenkins pick it up with the [generic webhooks plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin), then maybe do a secondary trigger from jenkins.
- Upgrade the bitbucket server and webhooks to jenkins plugin. The server 4.13 does not work well with later webhooks to jenkins plugin. A paid version of the plugin probably is your best choice.
- Or try bamboo that comes with the ["plan banches" feature](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you configure GIT - push, commit... etc hooks, be sure to check the JENKINS git selection, and set the BRANCH to check for (** specifies all branches) and most importantly,

USE localtunnel.me or similar to set your JENKINS online or it won't work.